# App crashing when adding second stepper

Tags: ios, swift

I have successfully got a step updating the values of a Text Field and now i am trying to add a second stepper but the app is now crashing.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var propertyTypeField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var insuranceTypeField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bedroomField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bathroomField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var doYouOwnPropertyField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var propertyYearField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bathroomStepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var bedroomStepper: UIStepper!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0xE1/255, green: 0xE1/255, blue: 0xE1/255, alpha: 1.0)


    //Bedroom stepper setup
    bedroomField.text = "\(Int(bedroomStepper.value))"
    bedroomStepper.addTarget(self, action: "stepperValueDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    //Bathroom stepper setup
    bathroomField.text = "\(Int(bathroomStepper.value))"
    bathroomStepper.addTarget(self, action: "stepperValueDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func viewTapped(sender : AnyObject) {

    propertyTypeField.resignFirstResponder()
    insuranceTypeField.resignFirstResponder()
    bedroomField.resignFirstResponder()
    bathroomField.resignFirstResponder()
    doYouOwnPropertyField.resignFirstResponder()
    propertyYearField.resignFirstResponder()

}

func stepperValueDidChange(stepper: UIStepper) {

    let bedroomStepperMapping: [UIStepper: UITextField] = [bedroomStepper: bedroomField]
    if !(bedroomField.text == ""){
    bedroomStepperMapping[stepper]!.text = "\(Int(stepper.value))"}

    let bathroomStepperMapping: [UIStepper: UITextField] = [bathroomStepper: bathroomField]
    if !(bathroomField.text == ""){
    bathroomStepperMapping[stepper]!.text = "\(Int(stepper.value))"}
}
```

This is the whole code i am using.

The error i am getting is

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Which line does it crash on? What does stepper.value contain?

Comment: >bedroomStepperMapping[stepper]!.text = "\(Int(stepper.value))"

Answer (score 0):

By using `!`  `bedroomStepperMapping[stepper]!.text` your telling the compiler there will be a value there.  As there is not one apparently you are getting the error.  Check if the value is nil before unwrapping it

To check for nil in the line you say is the issue

```
if !(bedroomField.text == ""){ 

    //Ok to unwrap object
 }
```

Comment: How do i check this value? I have set the text field to be default "0" and the stepper has its Current setting on "0" aswell

Comment: Show us how you are setting these values to 0

Comment: bedroomField.text = "0"
        bathroomField.text = "0"

and the steppers are set to zero in the Attributes Inspector.

Comment: Surely `bedroomField text` should be either `!` or `?` can you update your question to show how you are actually doing this. I have updated my answer

Comment: added all the code for you too look at.  Thanks a lot by the way.

Comment: Why are you setting your `bedroomField.text = "0"` and, to the stepper value ` bedroomField.text = "\(Int(bedroomStepper.value))"`  in viewDidLoad? One is redundant?

Comment: Was experimenting, sorry deleted now.

Comment: Ah ok so now try the code while checking for nil before unwrapping the values in `func stepperValueDidChange(stepper: UIStepper) {`

Comment: Hey, i'm still getting crashes when i click on either stepper.  I've updated my code, can you have another look please.  Thank you.

Comment: So you know then that the crash is not related to a nil value in the text field ,  now try checking for `nil` `int` value in the stepper as the other user has shown in their answer

Comment: When i try the other users code i get an error, "Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type".      if let bedroomField = Int(stepper.value){ bedroomStepperMapping[stepper]!.text = "(Int(stepper.value))" }

Answer (score 0):

While if you are using the optional value first check if value exist if not then there must not b null so do it as

```
if let bedFeild = Int(stepper.value) {
bedroomStepperMapping[stepper].text = bedFeild
}
```

Now there will be no crash if the value exist then value will be assigned to it else no without any crash

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, i tried your fix and it does not work.  i get the error, "Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type"  the code looks like this...  

    if let bedroomField = Int(stepper.value){
        bedroomStepperMapping[stepper]!.text = "\(Int(stepper.value))"
    }

Comment: in if statement it should be 

bedroomStepperMapping[stepper].text = bedroomFeild

Comment: `if let bedroomField = Int(stepper.value){
        bedroomStepperMapping[stepper].text = bedroomField}` -  is this correct? i am getting the same error and additional error, - "/'UIStepper' is not convertible to 'DictionaryIndex<UIStepper, UITextField>'"

Answer (score -1):

```
func stepperValueDidChange(stepper: UIStepper) {
    if bedroomStepper == stepper{
        bedroomField.text = "\(Int(stepper.value))"}
    if  bathroomStepper == stepper{
        bathroomField.text = "\(Int(stepper.value))"}
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: well it stopped the app crashing?

Comment: When posting an answer to your own question, please provide a short explanation, not just a piece of code. Thanks.